# Как получить исходный код из .apk-файла?

Tags: java, android, дизассемблирование

Как декомпилировать `.apk`-файл?

Comment: никак? ну или apktool может помочь.

Comment: Какого плана ответ Вы хотите получить? Полный процесс декомпиляции, думаю, никто описывать не будет, но Вы можете найти множество информации в интернете по запросу, например, «декомпиляция apk», а потом задать какой-то *конкретный* вопрос. Но вообще дело это непростое и не всегда результативное.

Comment: apk не содержит исходного кода, следовательно никак.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

apk содержит только байт-код (файлы .smali, а не исходники), который можно получить утилитой apktool (или другими на ее основе). Байт-код можно преобразовать в java-код утилитами dex2jar и в "исходники" утилитой jd gui (или другими на их основе).

Однако назвать полноценным исходником полученный результат можно с большой натяжкой, чаще всего из таких "исходников" невозможно вновь собрать рабочий apk, не проделав титанический труд.

Читаемость таких "исходников" тоже, мягко говоря, под вопросом. Результат примерно аналогичен машинному переводу: русский - английский - французкий - русский, то есть никакой.

Comment: Хорошее сравнение с машинным переводом.

Comment: Только с языками при этом лучше.)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться одним из apk декомпиляторов, например [этим](http://www.decompileandroid.com/), 
или [этим](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk). В интернете можно найти много информации по декомпиляторам, так и гайдов/доков по ним.